# iframe design changing back to old design on page reload

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, iframe

I styled an external iframe [here](http://www.informatixtech.com/expostars/tradeshow-calendar/) by following @SequenceDigitale.com answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe). Everything is good but when I sort the table data or search within that iframe, the page reloads but old design comes up. Why is that?

**Code**
I am using this code to fetch data from external resource

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents('http://www.exhibition-directory.com/expostars/index.php/');
$content = str_replace('</title>','</title><base href="http://www.exhibition-directory.com/expostars/" />', $content);
$content = str_replace('</body>','<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.informatixtech.com/expostars/wp-content/themes/hotstar-child/hotstar-child/custom.css" type="text/stylesheet" /></body>', $content);
$content = str_replace('</head>','<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.informatixtech.com/expostars/wp-content/themes/hotstar-child/hotstar-child/custom.css" type="text/stylesheet" /></head>', $content);
echo $content;

?>
```

and this is my iframe code

```
<?php
                echo '<iframe id="iframe" src="http://www.informatixtech.com/expostars/search-page.php" name="Stack" height="1200" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" width="100%"></iframe>';?>
```

Comment: because when you submit  the form it goes to http://www.exhibition-directory.com/expostars/index.php rather than your script, you need to proxy all requests

Comment: @MichailStrokin any hint how to proxy, i am not too expert. I just dont want my entire work to be wasted. Thanks

Comment: Does the form submit by ajax on other site , or through default browser form submit? You definietly need a proxy for the links so that each link points to your server to get a new version pulled from external site to be rendered

Comment: @charlietfl no its simple request, no ajax

Comment: You need to intercept all the clicks on links and send that url to your server, use the url sent to get new page. Same with form

Comment: I'll add a new answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the form uses $_GET variables, so you might do something like

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.exhibition-directory.com/expostars/index.php?'.http_build_query($_GET));
```

so that all variables passed to the form are appended to the fetched URL

Add this so that form submits to your server instead:

```
$content = str_replace('<form name="searchForm" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="get">','<form name="searchForm" action="http://www.informatixtech.com/expostars/search-page.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="get">', $content);
```

update your CSS so that it doesn't rely on form[action=index.php]

**update**:
Add this so that links are rewritten:

```
$content = str_replace("location.href='index.php?","location.href='http://www.informatixtech.com/expostars/search-page.php?", $content);
```

one more replace:

```
str_replace('<div class="sc-button-reset"><a href="index.php','<div class="sc-button-reset"><a href="http://www.informatixtech.com/expostars/search-page.php', $content);
```

Comment: actually it wont work, because you rely on other resources hosted on exhibition-directory

Comment: it doesn't work now because the server returns blank page instead of the page with the results, can you update the gist with the exact code you're using?

Comment: Sorry, I've typed 'search-form.php' instead of 'search-page.php', please update it and it should work fine (in the last line)

Comment: Sorry, mistyped that URL again :) you need to use your own URL (http://www.informatixtech.com/expostars/search-page.php) rather than exhibition-directory :)

Comment: use something like form[name='searchForm'] instead of form[action='index.php'] in your css as well so that it still looks good

Comment: i think it is not replacing actually

Comment: it does work as expected, just update the CSS so that it looks good

Comment: oh yes search button is working but not the other one, I think i have to replace code for that button in the same way. right?

Comment: right :) I've updated the answer with the last change you need :)

Comment: you are really great :)

Comment: thank you so much for helping and teaching me something new :)

Answer (score 0):

Within the pages you scrape and return in iframe add click handlers to all the links that require reload.

Using jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        var otherSiteHref = encodeURIComponent(this.href);
        var yoursSiteProxyUrl ='/path/to-your-php?url=' + otherSiteHref ;
        this.href = yoursSiteProxyUrl ;
    });
});
```

Then at server decode the `$_GET['url]`, get the new html from remote site and deliver it.

For the form, set up a controller method in your php and change the action to point to your proxy

```
$('#searchForm').attr('action', '/your-search-proxy.php');
```

You will need to make a cURL request to other site for the search form.

Comment: this might be a better approach but it won't work without JS